# primefaces 3.3<p:fileupload> always allow users to select several files. how to prevent it for video upload?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using p:fileupload of primefaces 3.3.1. I use to have 2.2 of primefaces to upload video file to my site.

now when I upgraded to 3.3.1 on the interface level it will always allow the user to select several videos each time when the user clicks the button "+ Choose". I really need to upload only one single video each time and the user should not have the possibility to select other than One video.

I have tried the option fileLimit="1" yet I was unsuccessful.

is there anyone familiar with this issue.

FYI behind the scene primefaces uses jquery file upload here is the link

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Also, if anyone knows nice way of uploading video to the server I'm willing to try it.

Thank you.

Comment: try `multiple="false"` also use `allowTypes` attribute to specify exact file extensions to accept.

Comment: @Daniel thank you but that wont do for the user still can click the button +Choose and select other files, what I want is once the user selects one file, not be able to select anther one. any other suggestion?

Comment: as long as you don't set `multiple="true"  ` the user will be able to upload only one file , the fact that he will be able to override the existing file several time is not a problem , if it is for you you can disable the `<p:fileUpload `with condition after successfull upload like this `<p:fileUpload disabled="#{myBean.fileWasUploadedSuccessfully}"....`

Comment: @Daniel with your tick I can upload as you said single video (the last one) ,the problem is the user is still be able to select multiple file. this behaviour will confuse the user. Here is the image after modifying as as you have said. http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=184421731690283&set=a.184421728356950.43916.100003673724617&type=3&theater

Comment: I said "as long as you don't ,.... I meant that you should use multiple="false"

Comment: @Daniel sorry I meant I set up as multiple="false" yet still the same behaviour. it still allow the user to choose as many image as possible. take a look the image I have posted for you.

Comment: hmm... yes, same on primefaces showcase , in that case I'd say go for the auto upload mode...  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf

Comment: You are welcome, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that if you don't want your user to be able to add multiple files (before uploading them) you should use the auto upload mode... [FileUpload - Auto](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml)